# Error while using webcam with cheese in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webcam, cheese

When I start cheese in the terminal, cheese throws this error:

```
 libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: 
 v4l-convert: libjpeg error: End Of Image (cheese:3077): cheese-WARNING 
 **: Internal data flow error.: gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): 
 /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin17
 /GstV4l‌​2Src:video_source: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
```

Answer (score 4):

In cheese go to settings and set the Photo Resolution down to 640x480 instead of 1280x720.

Comment: You're losing it!  You're showing up in the LQ review queue!  :P (+1 to get you out)